# RoleInstanceStatusCheckEventArgs.SetBusy from inside w3wp

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, w3wp, webrole

I am calling the RoleInstanceStatusCheckEventArgs.SetBusy from inside w3wp process where i have registered for the statuscheck event. This is similar to as explained in the following link except that this link talks about doing it inside WaIISHost while i am doing it inside w3wp.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleenvironment.statuscheck.aspx

The issue I am hitting is that the role remains busy for 5 minutes and then automatically comes online(Ready). Has anyone ever hit this before? Can SetBusy not be called from inside w3wp?

Thanks for any help/pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the w3wp process is getting killed.  You should be able to do this but IIS/Azure can kill and restart the w3wp process.  You may need to check the Process ID to see if that is the case.

But what you want to do, you should be able to do.